# Yes/ No: Is $W=\{ V : V \in \mathbb{R}^n \text{and} \ v_1v_2 = 0\}$ is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $V = (v_1,v_2, ........., v_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$

then   $W=\{ V  : V \in \mathbb{R}^n  \text{and}  \ v_1v_2 = 0\}$  is  a subspace  of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

My attempt :  i think  yes  . For  subspace $k(v_1v_2) = 0 \in W $, where  $k$ scalar muliple

Is its true ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n=3$, the vectors $(1, 0, 0)$ and $(0, 1, 0)$ belong to $W$. Does their sum also belong to $W$?

Comment: very good  logics @Angryavian

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not a subspace.

Consider the two vectors

$\vec x_1 = (1, 0, 0, \ldots, 0) \tag 1$

and

$\vec x_2 = (0, 1, 0, \ldots, 0); \tag 2$

then

$\vec x_{1, 1} = 1; \; \vec x_{1, 2} = 0, \tag 3$

and

$\vec x_{2, 1} = 0; \; \vec x_{2, 2} = 1; \tag 4$

so each $\vec x_i$, $i = 1, 2$ satisfies

$\vec x_{i, 1} \vec x_{i, 2} = 0, \tag 5$

but

$\vec x_1 + \vec x_2 = (1, 1, 0, \ldots, 0) \tag 6$

fails to satisfy the requisite property, and since subspaces are by definition closed under addition . . . the conclusion is most easily seen.

It is worth noting that this holds if $\Bbb R^n$ is replaced by $\Bbb F^n$ for any field $\Bbb F$.

Comment: thanks u @Robert lewis sir

Comment: @jasmine:  you are most welcome my friend!  Cheers!